# For loop - How to overcome replacement has length zero problem in R?

Tags: r

I'm getting replacement has length zero problem at the end of for loop. OK, I know this error indicates NULL or a length 0 vector. I tried a few solutions but none of them works. How to escape from na/0 result and continue loop?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,3] <- ... #that doesn't matter
  if(length(df[i,3] == 0)){
    df[i,3] <- "Not found"
  }
}

Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero
```

or

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,3] <- ... #that doesn't matter
  if(is.na(df[i,3] == TRUE){
    df[i,3] <- "Not found"
  }
}

Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Example:

```
column1      column2          column3
   a      www.example.com/a     100
   b      www.example.com/b     150
   c      www.example.com/c     NA
   d      www.example.com/d     NA
```

And so on... My aim is to skip the link (c) that it cannot find and to keep the loop running.

Comment: Try with `sum` instead of `length`. In your logical expression, the `length` is not returning a logical vector `length(1 == 1)`  I think you need just `if(df[i, 3] == 0)` In the second code block, `if(is.na(df[i,3]))`

Comment: maybe you want `if ( length(df[i, 3]) == 0 ) {`

Comment: Thanks but it's not working.

Comment: "Thanks but it's not working." When I use that code, it ____ and here's the error I get, or here's how it's different than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a for-loop to transform the column, why not use the dplyr::mutate function?

```
library(dplyr)

testFrame <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(0,1,1,NA,0))

testFrameEdited <- testFrame %>% 
  mutate(b = ifelse(b == 0 | is.na(b), 'Not found', b))

testFrameEdited
```

Returns

```
  a         b
1 1 Not found
2 2         1
3 3         1
4 4 Not found
5 5 Not found
```

Comment: The main purpose is not to find what is value. For loop finds some values ​​according to the links, but the loop ends when the link of the nth row is not working. Other links are working, but can't find them. My aim is to skip the link that it cannot find and to keep the loop running. I added an example the above.